# Eclipse memory analyser - error on trying to acquire heap dump

Tags: java, memory, weblogic-10.x, heap-dump

I am trying to acquire heap dump using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT).  I have Weblogic 10.3 app server running.  It's a windows XP OS with 32 bit Java installed.  When I try to acquire heap dump using MAT for the process that's running Weblogic, I am getting the following error:

```
Error creating heap dump. jmap exit code = 1
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.readInt(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:226)
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.execute(WindowsVirtualMachine.java:88)
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.executeCommand(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:195)
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.dumpHeap(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:162)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.dump(JMap.java:224)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:122)

Error creating heap dump. jmap exit code = 1
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.readInt(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:226)
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.execute(WindowsVirtualMachine.java:88)
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.executeCommand(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:195)
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.dumpHeap(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:162)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.dump(JMap.java:224)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:122)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could try is using `jmap` to save the dump and open it in MAT.

Use `jps` to get the process id (pid).

```
jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=myfile.hprof <processid-from-above>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But jmap does not work on Windows.  I tried using jConsole, but even that's giving problems.  Is there any other way I can get a live heap dump?

Comment: You can try VisualVM or jVisualVM. One comes with Java and the other is a separate download.

Comment: For future reference, JMap does work in Windows and is included in JDK > 1.5 (I think).  You need to have the JDK installed, not just the JRE (JDK is the "Development Kit" and has extra tools).  Then you must navigate to the `bin` of the JDK installation to run `jmap`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I was able to use jmap but I only got a 20mb dump of a process taking up 1.3GB of memory. Something isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem on Windows, I solved by open `cmd.exe` as Administrator.

Comment: Something I love about StackOverflow.  A 9 years old question can come to life. :)